# how to get all parent nodes of given element in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I mean an array of them. That is a chain from top HTML to destination element including the element itself.

for example for element `<A>` it would be:

```
[HTML, BODY, DIV, DIV, P, SPAN, A]
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A little shorter (and safer, since `target` may not be found):

```
var a = document.getElementById("target");
var els = [];
while (a) {
    els.unshift(a);
    a = a.parentNode;
}
```

Comment: I changed accepted answer. This is the most elegant. (btw, The tests show that push and then reverse is more efficient.) [I wish there was an option to accept more than one answer, even at cost of my points.]

Comment: This will include the document node. If you wish to stop at the `HTML` element, then change 'a = a.parentNode' to `a = a.parentElement`

Comment: More elegant, just for fun: `const parents = node => (node.parentElement ? parents(node.parentElement) : []).concat([node]);`

Comment: @rsk82 9.5 years later and `push`+`reverse` is still 400% faster. Wow.

Comment: There's no reason to use `unshift` here. It's quadratic time complexity.

Comment: @ggorlen How many levels deep does the typical HTML page go? We're talking about depths you can count on your hands. You're optimizing unnecessarily. This is a perfect example of when you should basically ignore performance entirely and write it *whichever way is clearest for human readers*. The performance just isn't going to matter in most cases. If you find a situation where it does, you should address it then (not before).

Comment: @Wayne We talked about this in another thread, but humans can understand `push` just as easily as `unshift`, yet using `push` eliminates a potentially serious and surprising performance problem that could crop up in an edge case. `push`/`reverse` comminicates intent and is much more readable to me than `unshift` is. "Premature optimization" only applies when you're making major readability sacrifices to improve the performance, not taking something for free. I don't think [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8729287/6243352) is any less readable than this, do you?

Comment: @Wayne It's my opinion that at the very least, when posting quadratic code, it behooves OP to at least state that it's quadratic, even if it seems that it's likely not going to be a problem due to the nature of _most_ DOM structures. There are always edge cases that can trigger problems. It's easy enough to add "I'm using `unshift` for readability/elegance but keep in mind that this algorithm is quadratic -- for most use cases, it won't matter since most HTML trees are flat".

Answer (score 26):

You can try something like:

```
var nodes = [];
var element = document.getElementById('yourelement');
nodes.push(element);
while(element.parentNode) {
    nodes.unshift(element.parentNode);
    element = element.parentNode;
}
```

Comment: +1. beat me to it as well, but instead of using `reverse()` at the end, i would just use `unshift()` instead of `push()`

Comment: Yes, instead of using reverse at the end, using unshift would be a way more efficient way of doing it. Answer edited.

Comment: @techfoobar technically `push()` and `reverse()` is *faster*, so it depends on your definition of "efficient". It really depends on the usage of the function, if its not used a performance critical section, `unshift` feels more natural to me. If it is a critical path, then I would go with the former.

Comment: +1 for that info. Still unshift makes the code look cleaner than push and reverse I'd say. If we're not dealing with 100s or 1000s of items in the array, the performance i guess wouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: +1. All this time I never knew `.push()` had a brother called `.unshift()`!

Comment: If we are all worrying about speed so much, why isn't it `var nodes = [element];` and swap first two lines, and remove the `push` before the loop. I think `push` all then `reverse` is faster too. Repeated `unshift` is going to be O(n^2) because you have to move more and more elements each iteration. `push` then `reverse` can leverage the array being push-optimized and reverse being in-place. Push are likely to be amortized constant time in reasonable implementations. `reverse` is O(n), in-place, super fast.

Comment: If the node doesn't exist, `element.parentNode` throws. And there's no reason to recommend `unshift` to save a line of code at the cost of a massive complexity hit.

Comment: @ggorlen there is absolutely a reason: human readability, which is almost always more important. You should treat it as more important until you have a defined, practical, direct reason not to. And no such reason not to has been demonstrated in this case. The node depth of a typical HTML page can be counted on your human fingers.

Comment: @Wayne I agree with you in general, but when the more efficient approach is pretty much a matter of using `.push` instead of `unshift` (`reverse` isn't integral to the algorithm, but adding that is hardly impactful to readability -- if anything, it improves it), it's not premature optimization. Sure, the depth is generally small, but in a hot loop it adds up. Ultimately, profile it, and at least document the complexity in the post. Anyway, the `unshift` thing is a pretty minor aside; my main beef is the potential for an unexpected crash. That's a serious issue for a post as upvoted as this.

Answer (score 8):

I like this method:

```
[...(function*(e){do { yield e; } while (e = e.parentNode);})($0)]
```

... where $0 is your element.

An upside of this method is that it can be used as a value in expressions.

To get an array without the target element:

```
[...(function*(e){while (e = e.parentNode) { yield e; }})($0)]
```

Comment: Shortest solution so far. If you want to remove the target element itself, you can add at the end `.slice(1)` and if you want to have the greatest parents first, `.reverse()`

Comment: In order to exclude the target element, it's easier to inverse the do-while into a while loop like this:

`[...(function*(e){while (e = e.parentNode) { yield e; }})($0)]`

(I have updated my answer)

Comment: I love it! Finally handy use of yield :-D

Answer (score 5):

You can walk the chain of `element.parentNode`s until you reach an falsey value, appending to an array as you go:

```js
const getParents = el => {
  for (var parents = []; el; el = el.parentNode) {
    parents.push(el);
  }

  return parents;
};

const el = document.querySelector("b");
console.log(getParents(el).reverse().map(e => e.nodeName));
```

```html
<div><p><span><b>Foo</b></span></div>
```

Note that reversing is done in the caller because it's not essential to the lineage algorithm. Mapping to `e.nodeName` is purely for presentation and also non-essential.

Note that this approach means you'll wind up with the document element as the last element in the chain. If you don't want that, you can add `&& el !== document` to the loop stopping condition.

The overall time complexity of the code above is linear and `reverse()` is in-place, so it doesn't require an extra allocation. `unshift` in a loop, as some of the other answers recommend, is quadratic and may harm scalability on uncommonly-deep DOM trees in exchange for a negligible gain in elegance.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative (based on [this](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-all-parent-elements-with-vanilla-javascript/#1-get-all-parents)):

```
for(var e = document.getElementById("target"),p = [];e && e !== document;e = e.parentNode)
p.push(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will likely be the most performant **in the long run** in the most scenarios if you are making frequent usage of this function. The reason for why t will be more performant is because it initially checks to see what kind of depths of ancestry it might encounter. Also, instead of creating a new array every time you call it, this function will instead efficiently reuse the same array, and slice it which is very optimized in some browsers. However, since there is no really efficient way I know of to check the maximum depth, I am left with a less efficient query-selector check.

```
// !IMPORTANT! When moving this coding snippet over to your production code,
// do not run the following depthtest more than once, it is not very performant
var kCurSelector="*|*", curDepth=3;
while (document.body.querySelector(kCurSelector += '>*|*')) curDepth++;
curDepth = Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log2(startDepth))),
var parentsTMP = new Array(curDepth);

function getAllParentNodes(Ele){
    var curPos = curDepth;

    if (Ele instanceof Node)
      while (Ele !== document){
        if (curPos === 0){
          curPos += curDepth;
          parentsTMP.length <<= 1;
          parentsTMP.copyWithin(curDepth, 0, curDepth);
          curDepth <<= 1;
        }
        parentsTMP[--curPos] = Ele;
        Ele = Ele.parentNode;
      }
    return retArray.slice(curPos)
}
```

The browser compatibility for the above function is that it will work in Edge, but not in IE. If you want IE support, then you will need a `Array.prototype.copyWithin` polyfill.

Answer (score -2):

get all parent nodes of child in javascript array

```
let selectedTxtElement = document.getElementById("target");
    let els = [];
    while (selectedTxtElement) {
         els.unshift(selectedTxtElement);
         selectedTxtElement = selectedTxtElement.parentNode;
    }
```

[know more](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/get+all+parent+nodes+of+child+in+javascript+array)

Comment: Variable names aside, this is identical to the accepted answer posted almost a decade ago. The link points to a non-legitimate Stack Overflow scraping/imposter site that stole the accepted answer from this thread... I'm not seeing any value here.