# Unlock text selection

Tags: javascript, locking, selection

I've got this script

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
    function bloquear(e){return false}
    function desbloquear(){return true}
    document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")
    if (window.sidebar){document.onmousedown=bloquear
    document.onclick=desbloquear}
</script>
(...)
<body onselectstart='return false'>
```

and it's working pretty fine.

But on certain pages I've got forms which I want to allow users to edit their comments.

I've googled it and found no solution to it.

Is it possible to unlock this feature into forms?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by returning false on selection start?  do you want to include this scripts many pages, and toggle its behavior depending on a variable in each specific page?

Comment: No, I've got a page with text, which I don't want students to copy and past into google to find out answers; but I want them to be able to answer input form, since they're on the same page

Comment: do you want the event handler to return false, unless the event occurred inside of a form element? is a jquery answer acceptable?

Comment: I ain't no programmer, so... 
anything that'll work is acceptable LOL :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I solved it for you, without jquery.  [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Uwz0flzc2uQOBiLFbMuv?p=preview)

on the selecStart event, we return false only if the event did not occur in a form element

```
 document.onselectstart= function(e){
   var t = e.target;
  var els = [];
   while (t) {
    els.unshift(t.tagName);
    t = t.parentNode;
  }

  return els.indexOf('FORM') !== -1;

 }
```

used the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729193/how-to-get-all-parent-nodes-of-given-element-in-pure-javascript) to get an array of all the parent elements

Comment: Thanks, @CodeToad, but it's not working, not even on the working example 
[link](http://i.imgur.com/1fH9DX4.png?1)

Comment: Many many many many many many thanks, dude! You're awesome! o/

Comment: glad to help. Buena suerte Eduardo :)