# Ignore all events from within a div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Say I have this div:

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'foobar';
div.innerHTML = '<button>foo</button>';
document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);
```

and I also use

```
 window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    // I want to ignore any events 
    // originating from within the div with id = 'foobar'  
 });
```

as noted in the comments, I want to ignore any events that originate from within the div with id = 'foobar', how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, using `Node.prototype.contains`:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {

    if (ev.target == div) {
      console.log('we can ignore this event...because its from the modal.');
      return;
    }


    let contains = div.contains(ev.target);
    if (contains) {
       console.log('we can ignore this event...because its from a child in the modal.');
       return;
    }

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

That work for me in chrome

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if(event.srcElement.id !== 'foobar' && event.srcElement.parentElement.id !== 'foobar') {
     console.log('this not comming from foobar')
  }
});
```

Comment: this only works for one level of child nesting right, that's not that great

Comment: You can combine it with that to get all parents: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8729274/2951051

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I think that using a built in call like contains() is better, see my answer

Comment: Yes. You have reason