# Is there an HTML element property that gives the level of that element in the document tree?

Tags: html, dom, document

I could probably implement such a function that checks "how deep" is that element in the document and determine its level.

However I would like to know if this information exists simply as is, such as a property of the element?

Comment: Nope. You'd need to count the parent/ancestor nodes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729193/how-to-get-all-parent-nodes-of-given-element-in-pure-javascript

Comment: Thanks, ill have a look at this question :)